# How to automate opening many files to a given line on zsh or bash

Tags: bash, zsh

I have a file generated by grep:

```
./filedir/file1.java:89:   contents of line 89
./filedir2/file2.java:123:   contents of line 123
./filedir3/file3.java:456:   contents of line 456
```

I'd like to open each file into my editor (IDEA) so I need to call:

```
idea --line 89 ./filedir/file1.java
idea --line 123 ./filedir2/file2.java
idea --line 456 ./filedir3/file3.java
```

I've tried combining sed and xargs and failing to find the secret mojo. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Scott, part of StackOverflow is showing us what you've tried, both so the answerers can see the effort you've put in and so they know what parts are confusing to you.

Comment: Here's what I was trying `sed 's|\(.*\):\(.*\):\(.*\)|--line \2 \1|' file.txt | xargs -I % idea %`

Comment: @ScottSanders , if my answer helped you in any way. please accept it by ticking the right symbol beside the answer.  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

```
<grep command> | while IFS=: read -r file line rest;do idea --line "$line" "$file" ;done
```

Here, grep result is split into 3 parts using `IFS=:` and used in sequence.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this doesn't work for me when I replace <grep command> with `cat infile.txt | while ...`

Comment: Specifically, I get a prompt back with `pipe while>`

Comment: Never mind... Was missing the `;done` that had scrolled off the end! Brilliant, thanks.